# Trouble with show/hide of a "div" JS;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make search with simple JS effects, but I am stuck at one place.
When I click on `.search` the div with `.s_holder` shows up, on another click it hides. The problem is, that when I click on `input` field or `div s_holder` - div with form hides.

```
<div class="search">
        <div class="s_holder">
            <form name="search" method="post" action="../test.php">
                <input type="search" name="query" placeholder="search">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
var a=true;
    $('.search').bind('click',function(){
        if (a==true){
        $('.s_holder').show();
            a=!a;
        }else{
            $('.s_holder').hide();
            a=!a;
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
    .search {
        background-image: url("../images/writers/search.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 52px;
        width: 52px;
        margin-right: 2%;
    }
    .s_holder{
        display: none;
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
        background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.12);
        height: 52px;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
    .search input[type=search]{
        margin-left: 65px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        width: 205px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: May be yo must try `(a===true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check that `e.target` property to see if the event has bubbled up from a child element. If it has, you can stop execution:

```
var a = true;
$('.search').bind('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target != e.currentTarget) // the click bubbled 
        return;

    if (a == true) {
        $('.s_holder').show();
        a = !a;
    } else {
        $('.s_holder').hide();
        a = !a;
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0kn5L09s/)

Comment: And how about `$('.search').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target != e.currentTarget) return;
    $('.s_holder').toggle(a);
    a = !a;
});`

Comment: This solution won't work. The menu doesn't collapse after it's open. See http://jsfiddle.net/ucmxk42k/ and my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is less simple that what it looks like.
When you show your div's content, the form and the div.s_holder come over it, intercept the clicks and prevent from clicking the original element.
You need to apply the click to all elements except the input field :

(Also, here's a much simpler code, without clumsy `if(a==true)` )

```js
$('.search, .s_holder, form').click(function(e){
    if(e.target != this) return;
    $('.s_holder').toggle();
});
```

```css
.search {
    background-image: url("../images/writers/search.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    border: blue solid 1px;
}
.s_holder{
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.12);
    height: 52px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.search input[type=search]{
    margin-left: 65px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 205px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
        <div class="s_holder">
            <form name="search" method="post" action="../test.php">
                <input type="search" name="query" placeholder="search">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9zgg3o75/2/